# Replacing character within a string

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a hangman game however i am not sure on how to update the word shown everytime the user selects a correct answer. I am using tkinter for buttons and boxes.

An example:

The word is **C O D E**.

user would see `_ _ _ _`

User guesses `D`.

I want the program to update `_ _ _ _` to `_ _ D _`

```
#replacing word

word_spaces = (" ".join(word))
word_miss = word_spaces.replace(word_spaces, " _ " * word_length)
word_list = ([word_spaces])

#Word Box

box = Label(window, text= word_miss, font= ("none", 50), bg= "black", fg= "white")
box.grid(row= 0, column = 1, columnspan= 9)

#Not sure about this part here:
def button_click(letter):
    if letter not in word:
        print("Not in word")
        #Add to letters guess
        #Tries -1
    elif letter in word:
        print("Letter in word")
            
        box.config(text= )
        #Add to letters guess
    else:
        print("Why is this here")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways to handle this, but here is what comes to mind right away.

Make a set of guessed letters:

```
guessed_letters = set()
```

When the user guesses a letter, add it to that set:

```
guessed_letters.add(user_input_letter)
```

Then, have it make a string of what you want to display using that set:

```
work = ""
for i in word:
    work += " "
    if i in guessed_letters:
        work += i
    else:
        work += "_"
    work += " "
box.config(text = work)
```

Sets are nice in that they hold on to things and can add, remove and access them with very little computation time, but they do not keep track of the order which they are added and items can only be added once (that is, it does not keep track of repeats.)  If you want those things, use a list instead:

```
guessed_letters = []
```

and

```
guessed_letters.append(user_input_letter)
```

or, you know, since it's always letters, you could just use a string:

```
guessed_letters = ""
...
guessed_letters += user_input_letter
```

There are other ways you could handle this all, like I said, so if this doesn't suit you, let us know.